# Dynamically creating and naming an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

Consider the following code snippet

```
for i = 1:100
    Yi= x(i:i + 3);   % i in Yi is not an index but subscript,
                    % x is some array having sufficient values
    i = i + 3
end
```

Basically I want that each time the `for` loop runs the subscript changes from 1 to 2, 3, ..., 100. SO in effect after 100 iterations I will be having 100 arrays, starting with `Y1` to `Y100`.

What could be the simplest way to implement this in MATLAB?

**UPDATE**

This is to be run 15 times

```
Y1 = 64;
fft_x = 2 * abs(Y1(5));
```

For simplicity I have taken constant inputs.

Now I am trying to use cell based on Marc's answer:

```
Y1 = cell(15,1); 
fft_x = cell(15,1); 

for i = 1:15
    Y1{i,1} = 64;
    fft_x{i,1} = 2 * abs(Y1(5));
end
```

I think I need to do some changes in `abs()`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to make variably-named variables in matlab. The common solution is to use a cell array for Y:

```
Y=cell(100,1);
for i =1:100
   Y{i,1}= x(i:i+3); 
   i=i+3;  
end
```

Note that the line `i=i+3` inside the `for`-loop has no effect. You can just remove it.

```
Y=cell(100,1);
for i =1:100
   Y{i,1}= x(i:i+3);   
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you suggest based on my update above.

Comment: Indexing a cell array is always done using curly brackets `{}`. If you change `fft_x{i,1}=2*abs(Y1(5));` to `fft_x{i,1}=2*abs(Y1{5});` I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make variably-named variables in matlab. If you really want this do something like this:

```
for i = 1:4:100
    eval(['Y', num2str((i+3)/4), '=x(i:i+3);']);
end
```

How you organize your indexing depends on what you plan to do with `x` of course...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dynamically name variables. However, it's almost never a good idea and there are much better/safer/faster alternatives, e.g. cell arrays as demonstrated by @Marc Claesen.

Look at the `assignin` function (and the related `eval`). You could do what asked for with:

```
for i = 1:100
    assignin('caller',['Y' int2str(i)],rand(1,i))
end
```

Another related function is `genvarname`. Don't use these unless you really need them.